# EPPLUS ExcelRange creates table starting in wrong row

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

In C# I have populated an excel file with data. Now I would like to create a table starting at  cell A2.
I am using the code below to create the table but instead of creating the table starting at Cell A2, the table is being created starting at cell A3

```
 using var package = new ExcelPackage(file);
           
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Name: "MainReport");

          
           var range = ws.Cells[Address: "A2"].LoadFromCollection(people, PrintHeaders: true);
            range.AutoFitColumns();

            //Formats Header row
            ws.Cells[Address: "A1"].Value = "My Data!";
            ws.Cells[Address: "A1:C1"].Merge = true;
            ws.Column(col: 1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            ws.Row(row: 1).Style.Font.Size = 24;
            ws.Row(row: 1).Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Pink);

            ws.Row(row: 2).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            ws.Row(row: 2).Style.Font.Bold = true;
            ws.Column(col: 3).Width = 20;
          
            //create a range for the table
            ExcelRange range_table = ws.Cells[2, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Row, ws.Dimension.End.Column];

            //add a table to the range
            ExcelTable tab = ws.Tables.Add(range_table, "Table1");

            //format the table
            tab.TableStyle = TableStyles.Medium2;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand it looks like the table starts at A2 to me. Is that screenshot "what you want to happen" or "what is happening"?

Comment: If your question is "how can I get rid the headers so the data starts in A2" have you tried setting PrintHeaders to false?

Comment: @CaiusJard when I open the name manager in excel, it states that Table 1 range is A3 to C7. So it its not including the header.
Also look at the green border in the image above. It goes from A3 to C7

Comment: I still don't get you. Can you add a screenshot to show what you expect it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Excel itself works so that if you select `A2:C4` and create a table and you say "has no Headers" it will put some generic headers in `A2:C2` and shift the data area (and the data if there is any) to `A2:C5`.

If you say "has Headers" the headers will be defined in `A2:C2`, too, but the data only is in `A3:C4`.

The real Excel obviously does some guessing whether headers are present or not and pre-ticks the box for you.

As stated [here in the API Documentation](https://www.epplussoftware.com/docs/5.0/api/OfficeOpenXml.Table.ExcelTableCollection.html#methods), there is no flag to define if headers are present in the range so there might be no guessing and it might be assumed it is "no" and the shifting as explained on top takes place.

If you take that into consideration you should be able to work it out.